Edits for no reason
I see there are many edits allowed from experienced users that have no useful edit summary and appear to make no attempt to actually improve experience
For instance see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/185288/revisions , number 10
Regular users making similar edits are regularly temporarily banned for low quality posts, so perhaps some consistency could be applied here.

The edit in the post you link was not made by a moderator. Apparently the edit was performed to reduce the image size. Ideally a comment should be included to explain an edit. Admittedly it would have been better to replace the image with mathjax.

a minor mistake then. Suggest action still needs to be taken, as there is no difference in the size

Maybe your browser does not show a difference? I see a difference in firefox..

This edit was made without moderator intervention because the editor has more than 2000 reputation points. So it is the first time I see it. If you think an edit makes the post worse, you can flag it (or start a potential edit war by reverting once you have sufficient reputation).

I have tried several times to flag these but get  automated generic responses bearing no relevance to issues

Every flag has been handled by a person and you have gotten the appropriate response for each of these. For what it's worth, flagging edits that you do not agree with is possible, but these are in almost all cases no issues that moderators have any handle on. The notable exceptions are edit wars and introducing something violating the code of conduct. For the rest, a well placed comment is the way to go. You can @-notify the editor to ask for clarification.

"Regular users making similar edits are regularly temporarily banned for low quality posts" Users without 2000 rep. simply can't make them. You should rethink the reasons why someone can get banned, because trying to incite conflicts is one of the main ones.

@Mithoron - so low effort posts are allowed when they come from the elders? This seems to be what you are saying. It seems hard enough for a regular user to even start climbing the reputation ladder when new questions are regularly downvoted or closed, answers moved to comments without discussion on both sides

In editing, suggestions are different from revisions. When you make suggested edit, 1 or 2 guys need to check it and software would even allow you adding just 1 letter. If it gets accepted, you get 2 reputation points though. With 2k rep. editing is free, but you'd not get any rep. from it.

So, if experienced user makes an edit, it can't be rejected. Other user would have to rollback it, or make a whole new edit reversing it. It would only happen if edit is harmful, not if it's low effort, or partial.

Indeed, as an experienced user you will have earned the privilege that edits will be applied directly. Therefore even minor seeming edits are now possible. Most of the times, these users employ this privilege as nondisruptive as possible. That basically means that it'll be applied to recently active questions/answers not the ones that are almost forgotten.
I think most of these trivial seeming edits still make an attempt readability. In the linked case it scales the image so that it actually fits on the page.

Regular users making similar edits are regularly temporarily banned for low quality posts, so perhaps some consistency could be applied here.

That is not entirely true.
Regular, or new, users can edit questions and these edits will be placed into a queue so that more experienced users can double check them. This is necessary for a few reasons. Firstly, spam can be weeded out early. Secondly, new users can be guided towards the best practices of editing. (There are plenty of new editors using MathJax wrongly.)
In consequence, from review, some edits may be rejected. If a majority of recent edits are rejected, it can trigger an automatic ban. I have not seen this happen very often. I have not seen this happen regularly by any means.
Before we go…
It's always a good idea to focus on posts that are recent. It's also quite a good idea to focus on posts with a positive score. If you think you can turn around a negative score of a post, give it a try - it's much appreciated.
For more on this, check out: What are some basic guidelines for good edits on Chem.SE?

A shame I see so many minor edits on old articles that do not add. For instance https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/103019/7 https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/49621/4
and minor edits that do tidy up are refused (does MM's answer at https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/185086/in-the-fischer-esterification-mechanism-what-happens-to-the-second-alcohol-grou/185105#185105 make sense? My flags on this are "Declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer" and my edits to improve the English are "promotional"

Your edits were an improvement but incomplete (you could have been more thorough). Evidently that triggered the rejection.

Prepare for your edit to also be rejected Buck - still incomplete from my reading

Well, I hope you are not discouraged from performing edits. It isn't always possible to get everything right, and as they say the perfect is the enemy of the good. Again, just try to be more thorough.

Always discouraged when rejection occurs without useful feedback, which then leads to bans

@jenny.essex The first link you posted is an author of a post correcting that post. That's something entirely different as it is no community contribution. You can always edit your own posts as long as you don't violate copyright. The second one corrected the title; sure it's not much, but now it fits the question. Your edit was rejected by the author of the post. I guess they simply didn't like what you have done to edit. Might be what you wrote in the edit statement. This post shows that you used flags, where you should have left a comment. We don't have many options to respond to flags.


I guess they simply didn't like what you have done to edit. Might be what you wrote in the edit statement.

Sure - that's possible, but then it is misuse of the "promotional" issue for rejection of the edit (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/413718/what-is-considered-promotional-content )

Where is it stated that your edits were rejected because they were regarded as promotional?

I guess if I stop reading before the comma, I could construe this meaning. The full reason is: This edit defaces the post in order to promote a product or service, or is deliberately destructive.  Your edits fit the second part, they appear deliberately destructive.

@Martin-マーチン - as opposed to edits that do not do anything other than force a question to the top of the "recent activity" pile, especially for those that have been dormant for over 5 (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/103019/7) or 8 (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/49621/4 ) years ?

You might message the editors directly. The editor of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/49621/4 often contributes to finding related older posts. The reason they performed the edit might be because they encountered a post related to a new question, and decided to edit and bring it to the fore. Yes, it was a small edit.

The editor of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/revisions/103019/7 is a veteran contributor. It was also a minor edit, and unclear why they did it but perhaps also upon encountering a related new question they caught sight of a minor issue that could use improvement.

Note these are opinions, but the overall assessment is that as users acquire more reputation they gain seniority on the site and are granted more freedom to make decisions. This is not a carte blanche, but neither is what they have done punishable.

And obviously, it's OK to not accept edits fitting your own agenda. As noted above I tried to further correct the English in https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/posts/185105/revisions but that was apparently destructive.
"It will be deprotonated by conjugate base of acid catalyst giving the final ester product and back the catalytic acid (that's why we called the reaction is acid catalyzed)." - good English?

@jenny.essex That really is something you should discuss in the comments to the post, or in chat (as mentioned previously). Right at this moment this discussion is taking up all of the time I have to spend on this site. I'm happy to have these conversations, but I have the feeling you are not trying to engage to find a compromise or understand the other side(s). If there isn't anything further, I'll be disengaging now.

@jenny.essex Thank you, I considered your comment and altered the edit.  There are participants here for whom English is a second language or for whom scientific writing is not yet second nature. There is no goal (or "agenda") here beyond helping make q&as clear and free of significant formatting, typographical, grammatical, spelling or other errors.
